# Помогите понять рекурсивную функцию в ANSI Common Lisp

Tags: рекурсия, lisp

Что-то не могу понять, как работает данная функция из книги ANSI Common Lisp:

```
(defun our-length (lst)
  (if (null lst) ;; когда пустой возвращаем ноль
    0
    (+ (our-length (cdr lst)) 1))) ;; а это что?
```

Как, я могу сложить cdr списка и единицу?

Comment: Складывается не `cdr` списка, а значение примененной к нему функции `our-length`, т.е. длина списка без первого элемента складывается с единицей: `(our-length '(a b))` → `(+ (our-length '(b)) 1)` → `(+ (+ (our-length '()) 1) 1)` → `(+ (+ 0 1) 1)` → `(+ 1 1)` → `2`

Answer (score 1):

`our-length (cdr lst)` - применяет функцию к хвосту списка. А уже к результату возврата добавляет единицу.

Допустим, в списке три элемента.

При первом вызове условие `if (null lst)` не выполняется. Происходит вызов `our-length` со списком в два элемента.

Условие опять не выполняется. Происходит вызов `our-length` со списком в один элемент.

И так до тех пор, пока не будет произведён вызов `our-length` с пустым списком. Тогда сработает условие и вернёт 0.

После чего станут проиходить возвраты из предыдущих вызовов. На кажом из них будет добавляться единица к результату.

Comment: Спасибо! Что-то начало прояснятся. Это значит когда функция вернет 0 следующий вызов плюсанет к нулю один далее к одному еще один, и так ко всем элементам списка...